Help identifying vintage paper and wax capacitor
I am repairing an old tube  radio and I can't recognise this paper wax capacitor. It says G 5000(x)380V. It is made by Koweg. I think it is an RFI  capacitor, but I can't tell its capacitance. What is best substitute for it?


It's rated at 380VAC, so a relatively high voltage part.
I would guess that the 5000 is the capacitance in pF (or \$\mu\mu\$F) but you can confirm that with a capacitance meter if it is still functional.
If you want to replace it, use a Y1 class safety capacitor of similar value (presumably something like 4.7nF).

@strmusicman The black band at one end doesn't mean it is a polarized capacitor, but likely indicates that it is wired to the outside foil (these caps are a sandwich of two foils and dielectric). The outside foil would go to the lower impedance part of a circuit - perhaps ground.

4.7 nf y1 class capacitor is the proper value  for sure?

No, it's not for sure, at least to me. That's why I suggest checking it with a capacitance meter. It's plausible, maybe likely or very likely. A schematic and a capacitance meter would assist in dispelling doubts.
